# What is it called when a series of photos taken over a few days is made into a video clip?

Tags: terminology, timelapse

I saw this on a National Geographic programs when they had recorded the sky for a few days and then make a few seconds long clip from it. What is this called?

Comment: I wanted the tag to be filming, but it didnt exsist and I need 300 rep to make a new tag, I didnt find any Filming forum so I went for Photography.

Comment: We have a [tag:video] tag. And, there is a whole sister site about audio and video production, at http://avp.stackexchange.com/. Generally, film/video/cinematography questions are off-topic here and should be asked there, except when the answers are relevant to still photography. (And timelapse is an area where there is significant overlap.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [Time-lapse Photography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-lapse_photography).

Comment: For further reading, our questions tagged "timelapse": http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timelapse